# is it possible to share hardware resources through network?

Tags: networking, home-networking, cloud

Suppose there are several laptops in my house and I would like to connect them and then in one of the laptops use their hardware resources (CPU, Graphic card and etc) to play a game that a laptop lonely is not able to run it . some thing like a cloud. Is it possible to do such thing? and if yes how?

Comment: What you want is not possible at least not how you describe it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some cases: Yes, you can use the resource from other networked computers to speed up tasks seemingly running on your own computers. E.g. when using distributed compiling. (Example: [distcc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distcc)). or you could run a counterstrike server on another computer and only run the client on your laptop.

However **for graphical games** the practical answer is no.

Most games do not handle lag well. And very few are written in such a way that they allow this.  That is not so say that it is not possible, just that 99% of all commercial games are not written that way.

<sup>The closest thing I can think of where it does work is if you have a game without many screen updates and run the program on a powerful desktop, then RDP/VNC/teamviewer/X11/.. to the computer running the games. But that does not quite match your questionwhich seems to be focused on gamed.</sup>

Comment: seems it is easy to do this for computational purposes, How do I can do such thing? what software does share the resources?

Comment: Cluster computing to share compute resources is an old thing. It is often used for High Performance Computing (think of scientific calculations, chemical molecule simulations, etc etc). However the applications are often specifically written with this in mind.

It is not my field, so I'll just add a link to Wikipedia. Always useful to get an idea and the links at the bottom of the articles usually explain things in a lot more detail than I can. [Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_cluster).

Answer (score 2):

You can't combine the power of more pc's over the network to play a game for example, but you could stream a game that is played on a powerful pc, and control it from a weaker pc. But as Hennes says, only a handful games support this. Steam OS is perfectioning this method, and in order for it to work well, you'd need to play your game with a controller, because Steam OS will be much better able to predict your movements and thus sends commands quicker to you than normally.

Another option would be to actually exchange hardware from one pc to the other, but again, and especially with laptops, this is not gonna give a huge boost.

The best option would definitely be to look into getting your laptop replaced for a new model that actually does what you want it to do, or get a PC instead of a laptop (because a PC is overall cheaper to build/get than a laptop in comparison to getting the same performance.